# Parse info from horoscopes site

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have written code for taking horoscopes from dailyhoroscopes.com site:

```
<?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.dailyhoroscope.com/?date=yesterday');

$needle = 'var ar_interps = ';
$needle_end = 'var ar_interps_love = ';

foreach($html->find('script') as $e)       
    if (strpos($e->innertext, $needle) !== false) {
        $json = substr($e->innertext, strpos($e->innertext, $needle));        
        $json = substr($json, 0, strpos($json, $needle_end));
        $json = str_replace($needle, '', $json);
        $json = str_replace(';  ', '', $json);
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
        echo '</pre>';
        }
?>
```

What is the best way to make the same only with html and javascript?

Comment: What exeactly do you mean?

Comment: he means fetching with ajax and then output it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way: this server doesn't support CORS. For Cross-origin-ressource-sharing see the wikipedia article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Cross-domain access policies do not allow web pages to access content loaded from other origins. In this case, this would not allow you to load data from `dailyhoroscope.com` unless your page was also on that domain.

Additionally, reusing their content without their permission is likely to constitute a copyright violation, and is kind of a dick move even if it isn't illegal, as it would end up generating load on their server. Don't do it.